# How to perform selective rbind on datasets in R

Tags: r, append, rbind

I am trying to use rbind to append different datasets countrywise. The list of the datasets is

```
data <- c('a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','bu3','bu4','c1','c3')
code <- c('a','b','bu',c)
```

The structure of the data is somewhat like this -

```
countrya1 <- c("a","a","a")
yeara1 <- c("1","1","1")
inca1 <- c("1","2","3")
a1 <- data.frame(countrya1,yeara1,inca1)
countrya2 <- c("a","a","a")
yeara2 <- c("2","2","2")
inca2 <- c("1","4","3")
a2 <- data.frame(countrya2,yeara2,inca2)
countryb1 <- c("b","b","b")
yearb1 <- c("1","1","1")
incb1 <- c("1","2","7")
b1 <- data.frame(countryb1,yearb1,incb1)
countryb2 <- c("b","b","b")
yearb2 <- c("2","2","2")
incb2 <- c("6","2","3")
b2 <- data.frame(countryb2,yearb2,incb2)
```

The code that I used to combine all the datasets is as follows -

```
df=NULL
for (i in length(data)){
df1 <-read.dta(data[i])
df <-rbind(df,df1)
}
```

This binds all the datasets together in df. 
Is there a way to bind a1,a2,a3 together and b1,b2,b3 together and so on. In short, I want to bind the datasets by 'code'. Is there a way to do it in R?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In your `for` loop, it should be `for(i in seq_along(data))`

Comment: With your example, the `read.dta` is giving me errors.  Please provide an example that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `split` the 'data' by creating a group without the numbers and then with `read.dta`, read the datasets and `rbind` the datasets of same name

```
lst <- lapply(split(data, sub("\\d+", "", data)), 
             function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, read.dta)))
```

If we want to use the 'code', then use `grep` by looping through the 'code'

```
lapply(code, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(grep(x, data, value = TRUE), read.dta)))
```

#### data

```
code <- c('a','b','bu','c')
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. Also, is there a way of doing this using loops (for-loop?)?

Comment: @Bhavya You may do `for(i in seq_along(code)){
    i1 <- grep(code[i], data, value = TRUE);
    lst <- vector("list", length(code));
    for(j in seq_along(i1)){
       lst[[i]][j] <- read.dta(i1[j]);
      }
     lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) do.call(rbind, x));
}

lst1` (not tested)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do here. But this is what I get: "Error in do.call(rbind, x) : second argument must be a list"

Comment: Also, I am very new to R and programming in general. I am sorry if it seems very obvious.

Comment: @Bhavya  You should have provided some example data in your post for others to test

Comment: @Bhavya Can you change it to `lst[[i]][[j]] <- read.dta(i1[j])`

Comment: It still shows the same error. I am not sure why this is not working. Ill add sample dataframes here. I myself dont have the datasets. Need to submit the code on an online server.

Comment: @Bhavya As I mentioned, I haven't tested it without an example.

Comment: I have edited the question to include some datasets (not dta format).